# CSS Have a div which can fit 5 li per row how to make 6 go to new line

Tags: css

So in my footer I display a bunch of menu links as column where each columns has like

```
Header Column
 Column Link
 Column Link
 ...
```

And I can fit 5 of these per row. What I want is that if the content user add a 6th Column that it wraps to next line and is underneath the first column header.

Right now it wraps to next line but seems to place it randomly at the next line depending on the  height of the 1st row.

Mark up looks like

```
 <ul id="mainMenuList">
  <li class="footerParentSubLists boldMenu"></li>
  <li class="footerParentSubLists boldMenu">..subitems</li>
  <li class="footerParentSubLists boldMenu">..subitems</li>
  <li class="footerParentSubLists boldMenu">..subitems</li>
  <li class="footerParentSubLists boldMenu">..subitems</li>
  <li class="footerParentSubLists boldMenu">..subitems</li>
  <li class="footerParentSubLists boldMenu">..subitems</li>
  ...
<ul>
```

Right for each column I am setting width, which leaves enough for 5 per row

```
.boldMenu {
    max-width: 170px;
    width: 170px;
}
```

Also floating left

Any ideas ?

Comment: could you please share your code here jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (CSS3, [not compatible with IE8](http://caniuse.com/css-sel3)) to make every (5n+1)th list element move to a new line:

```
#mainMenuList > li:nth-child(5n+1) {
    clear: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/J4gQP/

If backwards compatibility is an issue, you can add a class directly to every (5n+1)th element yourself, or write JavaScript to do it for you, and `clear:left` that class as well.

Comment: but beware of, this is CSS3 and not compatible to each browser yet

Comment: or try to give them a min-width so that just 5 element fit the row and let all float left. but then the parent container (in your case the ul-element) must have a width too.

Comment: @algorhythm I have that set up, the problem is that they are not left aligning in second row

Comment: make the ul-element { position:relative; } and the li-elements { display: block; } to float them left...